# SSAS Calculated Member Aggregation Issue

Tags: ssas, mdx, multidimensional-cube

I have a very simple Calculated Member:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Account].[Account Parent].&amp;[NA_1].[Beginning Subscribers]
  AS -[Account].[Account Parent].&amp;[Beginning_Subscribers]
```

However, the Parent doesn't seem to calculate or simply ignores the Calculated member in Excel.  See below:

[image: Unwanted Image]

It should look like this:

[image: Wanted Image]

[Account Dimension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5a1aU.png)

This is the MDX on the Excel side:

```
Select /* Grid - 'Sheet1'!$A$1 */ Non Empty {[Calendar Month].[Calendar Month Parent].&[2018-11],[Calendar Month].[Calendar Month Parent].&[2018-12]} On Columns, Non Empty AddCalculatedMembers ( DrillDownMember ( AddCalculatedMembers ( {Descendants([Account].[Account Parent].&[Net_Mig_1],[Account].[Account Parent].&[Net_Mig_1].Level,AFTER)} ) , { [Account].[Account Parent].&[Net_Mig_1],[Account].[Account Parent].&[NA_1] } , Recursive ) ) On Rows From [TEST CALCS] Cell Properties VALUE
```

Comment: Please provide mdx, produced by excel, and Account dimension data.

Comment: Select Non Empty {[Calendar Month].[Calendar Month Parent].&[2018-11],[Calendar Month].[Calendar Month Parent].&[2018-12]} On Columns, Non Empty  AddCalculatedMembers (  Hierarchize (  DrillDownMember ( {[Account].[Account Parent].&[Net_Mig_1]} ,  { [Account].[Account Parent].[All],[Account].[Account Parent].&[Rollup Account],[Account].[Account Parent].&[Subsribers],[Account].[Account Parent].&[Net_Mig_1],[Account].[Account Parent].&[NA_1] }  , Recursive )  , Post )  )  On Rows From [TEST CALCS]  Cell Properties VALUE

Comment: This is more correct.  I had edited it a few times since the original post.  Select 

/*
Grid - 'Sheet1'!$A$1
*/

Non Empty {[Calendar Month].[Calendar Month Parent].&[2018-11],[Calendar Month].[Calendar Month Parent].&[2018-12]} On Columns, Non Empty  AddCalculatedMembers (  DrillDownMember (  AddCalculatedMembers ( {Descendants([Account].[Account Parent].&[Net_Mig_1],[Account].[Account Parent].&[Net_Mig_1].Level,AFTER)} )  ,  { [Account].[Account Parent].&[Net_Mig_1],[Account].[Account Parent].&[NA_1] }  , Recursive )  )  On Rows From [TEST CALCS]  Cell Properties VALUE

Comment: @Alex Sham As far as the Dimension data, I think this is what you are asking for.  It is a Parent Child Hierarchy.  Child Parent
Net_Mig_1 Subscribers
NA_1 Net_Mig_1
Acquisitions NA_1
Ending_Subscribers NA_1
Gross_Additions Net_Mig_1
Net_Deactivations Net_Mig_1

Comment: Speaking about your mdx: I’m not able to understand it, why are there drilldown, descendant functions, if you use simple member*-1?Where are measures?Account seems to be a dimension.Provide full structure,pls.
Can you write simple mdx to check your formula for member? 

    WITH MEMBER my_member as IIF([Account].[Account Parent].currentmember is [Account].[Account Parent].&[Beginning_Subscribers],-1, 1) *  your measure
 select my_member on columns,  Non empty [Account].[Account Parent].&[NA_1].Children on rows
from [TEST CALCS]  WHERE ([Calendar Month].[Calendar Month Parent].&[2018-11])?

Comment: I am new to MDX and we are using an Excel addin called XLCubed to view the data in our cube.  I copied that code from XLCubed.  Account is a dimension and Beginning Subscribers is a Calculated Member I am trying to add to the existing Account Dimension and include it in the NA_1 level of that Dimensions Hierarchy.  There is only one Measure in the cube called Value.

Comment: I ran your code above and it came back with "my_member" and no data so it looks like the formulas do the same thing.